# How to set page margins for xsl stylesheet without using <fo:

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, margins

I am amending an existing xsl stylesheet template. I would like to set page properties for when it is formatted into PDF.

I tried using

```
<fo:simple-page-master master-name="all" page-height="297mm"  page-width="210mm" margin-top="5cm" margin-bottom="5cm" margin-left="5cm" margin-right="5cm">
```

and then  for example

```
<fo:block break-after="page">
```

but nothing works.

The stylesheet doesn't use any formatting objects at the moment, is this a reason? Is there a way to set page properties without using formatting objects?

Edit: It is quite confusing whether the XSL-FO and XSL are the same thing, but it looks like the template I have is using HTML and then it is converted into PDF. So Does it mean I cannot mix it with XSL-FO? What to use then to set page properties?

Comment: If it is confusing for you ... it is even more confusing to us when you show two lines of something we have to guess at the rest. no one can answer your question unless you provide sufficient information.

Comment: The step 'then it is converted to PDF' is the important one. You'll have to find out how that is done. Page margins are set in that step. XSL-FO is one possible technique for converting XML to PDF, but there are others.

Comment: @Hobbes. Thank for the tip.  the converter is using Winnovative WnvHtmlConvert for Net. So if it doesn't support xsl-fo, is there any other way to set page margins other than on software level, which also cannot be done?

Comment: From their website, I suspect they're using CSS Paged Media to control the formatting. If you have a CSS file that specifies @page, it's CSS paged media.https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/#some-examples